# How do I toggle my "read More" with CSS only

Tags: html, css

Looking for solutions in CSS only.
I have story section on my website, but I only want to display a small part of each story, and the reader can click the "Read More..." if they want to read the rest of the story. This works for me,  But I want the "Read more..." to go away when it is clicked, as a "read less" appears at the bottom of the story, so reader can minimize it again after reading it.  Here is a link to my code: [My code @js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jim54729/1vkd6jdq/)

```
<span id="myReadMore">
  <h4>First part of the static content</h4>
  <p>
      <label for="inputShownContent3">
        <span>Read more....</span>
      </label>
  </p>
</span>
<br />
<input type=radio id="inputShownContent3" name="group3" />


<span id="spanHiddenContent3">
  <p>toggle the second part of the story.</p>

  <label for="inputHiddenContent3">
    <span>Read less....</span>
  </label>
</span>
<input type=radio id="inputHiddenContent3" name="group3" />
```

And my Css,

```
input#inputHiddenContent3,#inputShownContent3 
{
  display: none;
}

span#spanHiddenContent3 
{
  display: none;
}

input#inputShownContent3:checked ~ span#spanHiddenContent3 
{
  display: block;
}

input#inputHiddenContent3:checked ~ span#spanHiddenContent3 
{
  display: none;
}
input#inputShownContent3:checked ~
  span#myReadMore
{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: I don't think your current HTML will permit that...you can't select upwards in the DOM. You might want to rethink your approach

Comment: Also, your HTML is invalid, `span` elements cannot contain block level elements like headings and paragraphs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```css
input#inputHiddenContent3,#inputShownContent3 {
  display: none;
}

span#spanHiddenContent3 {
  display: none;
}

input#inputShownContent3:checked ~ span#spanHiddenContent3 {
  display: block;
}

input#inputHiddenContent3:checked ~ span#spanHiddenContent3 {
  display: none;
}

input#inputShownContent3:checked ~ #myReadMore p {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type=radio id="inputShownContent3" name="group3" />
<span id="myReadMore">
  <h4>First part of the static content</h4>
<p>
  <label for="inputShownContent3"><span>Read more....</span></label>
</p>
</span>
<br />


<span id="spanHiddenContent3">
            <p>      toggle the second part of the story. </p>

    <label for="inputHiddenContent3">
                  <span>Read less....</span>
    </label>
</span>
<input type=radio id="inputHiddenContent3" name="group3" />
```

I moved the hidden checkbox upward a bit in the HTML (as a comment said, you can't query backwards). In addition, I added a selector similar to your original that selects the paragraph containing "Read More" and hides it when the checkbox is active.

Use of a checkbox and the checked property was actually a pretty nifty way of doing this...thanks for teaching me something!

EDIT: Did not notice some of your own CSS rules trying to do the same thing. So, some parts of this are probably excessive and could be trimmed out. Unfortunately, I'm lazy.

Comment: Thanks, both, I can fix the improper html coding, and now I have the solution that works the way I was trying to get it to work. Having the "read more..", staying there was annoying.