# How to add dots after certain length of characters in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate

// Looking for this kind of text in my UI

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur........."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I toggle my "read More" with CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30916957/how-do-i-toggle-my-read-more-with-css-only)

Comment: First, read this on how to ask questions correctly [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And the answer, by the way. In css you cannot add an ellipse after a certain number of characters, you can do it in js, e.g. with this library [show-more](https://tomik23.github.io/show-more/#ellipsis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use text-overflow css property.

```css
p {
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectet</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

in a class or in the specific div's CSS properties.

Check [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/).

Please notice that in this solution you are not defining the number of characters after which the text will be truncated, but you should define the dimension of the element containing the text.

Check [here](https://caniuse.com/?search=ellipsis) where it's supported.

Answer (score 0):

1. [**white-space**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) property sets how white space inside an element is handled.

   `nowrap` collapses white space as for normal.
2. [**overflow**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) sets the desired behavior for an element's overflow.

   `hidden` content is clipped if necessary to fit the padding-box.
3. [**text-overflow**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) CSS property sets how hidden overflow content is signaled to users.

   `ellipsis` value will display an ellipsis

Code:

```css
p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate
</p>
```